# Do Loop For Sets of Variables

Tags: procedural-programming

Can I create a `Do` loop where instead of varying only 1 variable, I vary multiple sets of variable ?

For example (the syntax is invented and only serves as a purpose to show what I mean):

```
list = {}
Do[
list = AppendTo[list,{a,b}],
{a,b,{{1,2},{3,4}}];
```

should give me

```
list
```

> {{1,2},{3,4}}

I really need to loop over the variables.

Comment: Why not something like `Table[g[a, b] /. Thread[{a, b} -> list], {list, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}]`?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your comment. I cannot use such structure because the variables are parameters inside a large function. In each loop I want to update specific parameters to specific values, while keeping other parameters the same.

Comment: Based on this and your other question, I have the nagging suspicion that you've chosen an architecture that is making simple substitutions and looping more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @J.M. here is my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfbfstrsbmorjvy/Calculation%20of%20Pull%20In%20Voltage.nb?dl=0

Comment: @J.M. as you can see in the beginning there are some parameters defined. For some of them, I want to do a parametric sweep. Maybe you have a better idea of how to do it.

Comment: You could use 
`Do[expr,{i,imin,imax},{j,jmin,jmax},{k,kmin,kmax}]`    
ParallelDo takes the same structure.

Comment: What about `list = {};Do[list = AppendTo[list,x],{x,{{1,2},{3,4}}];`? Note however that using `Append` in loops will slow things down considerably as it involves a lot of copy operations. Solutions based on `Sow` and `Reap` (or even better: [``Internal`Bag``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762/8248900)) should yield better performance.

Comment: @Rby yes, this is an option, however, I will then get some combinations that I don't want

Answer (score 2):

1. Pass a list of parameter-tuples to `Table`
2. Unpack the tuples into the variables you want

Example:

```
Table[
 Block[{a, b},
  {a, b} = pair;
  a^2 + b^2
 ], {pair, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}}
]
```